# JavaScript - output one of many top hits at random

Tags: javascript, random, reduce

So here I have a system that identifies the object with the highest `count`, however as we can see there are two objects that both have the highest `count`. What I want to be able to do is take the top counts, however many that may be, and output one at random. How can I do this?

```
 var objects = [
    {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    {username: 'john', count: 5},
    {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
];

var res = objects.reduce(function(resObj, obj) {
  return resObj.count > obj.count ? resObj : obj
})

console.log(res);
```

Thanks!

Comment: This code works well if you don't care which value it returns. You actually want true random though, not just the first in a list?

Comment: True random yes, so I don't want it to output the same answer every time..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question here is how you can do it

**Note**: I added a few more of the same counts to show you how this works regardless of how many matches you have:

[Working example](https://jsbin.com/lusifes/2/edit?js,console)

```
 var objects = [
    {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    {username: 'john', count: 5},
    {username: 'amy', count: 5},
    {username: 'adam', count: 5},
    {username: 'fenty', count: 5},
    {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
];
// make an array to push same counts
var arr = [];

var res = objects.reduce(function(resObj, obj) {
  // keep track of (and set) max count
  var max = Math.max(resObj.count, obj.count);
  // if count is equal push to our array
  if (max === obj.count) {
    arr.push(obj);
  }
  // same code as before
  return resObj.count >= obj.count ? resObj : obj;
});

// get random index from our array
var randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

// get random result from our objects that have the same count:
console.log(arr[randIndex]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer using simple for loops. Returns random heightest object

```
function getHighest(objects) {
    var highest = 0;
    var heighestArr = [];
    // first get highest index
    for(var i=1; i<objects .length;i++){
         if(objects[i].count > objects[highest].count){
              highest= i;
         }
    }
    // then add all the highest ones in an array  
    for(var i=0; i<objects .length;i++){
         if(objects[i].count === objects[highest].count){
              heighestArr.push(objects[i])
         }
    }
    // return random from that array
    return heighestArr[Math.floor(Math.random()*heighestArr.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var objects = [
    {username: 'mark', count: 3},
    {username: 'dave', count: 5},
    {username: 'john', count: 5},
    {username: 'lucy', count: 2},
];

var res = objects.slice(1).reduce(function(resObj, obj) {
  if (resObj[0].count > obj.count) {
    return resObj;
  } else if (resObj[0].count === obj.count) {
    return [...resObj, obj];
  } else {
    return [obj]
  }
}, [objects[0]])

var randomElement = function(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

console.log(randomElement(res));
```

Untested but this is the basic idea.